# getting UserWarning: Boolean Series while printing dataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

While using pandas to print the datFrame i'm getting into the  `UserWarning` error

Below is my dataFrame:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/home/karn/plura/Test/Python_Pnada/Cyber_July.csv', usecols=['Platform ID', 'Safe', 'Target system address', 'Failure reason'])

hostData = data[data['Platform ID'].str.startswith("CS-Unix-")][data['Safe'].str.contains("^CS-.*DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT$")] [['Platform ID', 'Safe', 'Target system address','Failure reason']]
```

Below is the Error code:

```
./CyberCSV.py:20: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
```

Comment: it's not an error, it's a warning. you're basically chaining 2 filters here, each is a boolean series, so you're trying to index a boolean series with another filter, and pandas needs a common index. Try using the & operator to chain your filters

Comment: @MrE, thnx for the inputs